# What are the differences between `Test Behaviours` and `Templates` in Citrus Framework?

Tags: citrus-framework

What are the differences between `Test Behaviours` and `Templates` in Citrus Framework?

Both seem to be made to extract a common set of test actions and reuse it in any number of test cases.

One obvious and important difference is that **Templates support parameters** while Test Behaviours **must** share test variables with the test cases to exchange data.

Are there any other notable differences? Will one of the two disappear in the near future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Templates are meant to be used in XML test cases only. TestBehaviors are meant to be used in JavaDSL test cases. You are free to add a local member variable to the TestBehavior implementation that is not shared with the test context and therefore not shared with the test case.

So bottom line both components provide exactly the same features - one for XML, one for JavaDSL.

Edit: Both are meant to remain in the framework in the future.